# How to get clients as a UI/UX beginner designer?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, portfolio

I am a UI/UX designer with only some screens of landing pages. I want to know if that will effective to get clients, if I build up some full imaginaries design projects from scratch?

Comment: This forum is meant primarily for user experience problem solving, not career advice or portfolio review. I would check Quora, and look up top top UX blogs to start searching. You'll find quite a lot of resources on this type of subject.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bloated question. UX covers many disciplines, UI Design/Site Hierarchy seems to be what your looking for but in this case just apply as a UI Designer.

## Read

If you want to learn about what UX is about check out [Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/) and give a few great UX books a read, I recommend the following:

- [Don't Make me Think : Steve Krug](https://www.amazon.ca/Dont-Make-Think-Revisited-Usability/dp/0321965515/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1540484145&sr=8-1&keywords=don%27t%20make%20me%20think)
- [The Design of Everyday things : Don    Norman](https://www.amazon.ca/Design-Everyday-Things-Revised-Expanded/dp/0465050654/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1540484145&sr=8-2&keywords=don%27t%20make%20me%20think)

Reading these should really open your mind to what UX is. After this understanding you'll see visual Designs are just a way of communicating your Strategy.

## Case Studies

If I was hiring a UX designer I would ask them to provide a case study for a relevant product. This would show me what disciplines and methodologies they understand and also show how they problem solve and focus on user centric design.

## UX Portfolio Course

There is a great tutorial at Udemy that shows how to build a case study:

[The Ultimate UX Portfolio Course](https://www.udemy.com/the-ultimate-ux-portfolio-course/learn/v4/)